# How to reduce large combinations?

Tags: probability, arithmetic, combinations, factorial

The result of a hypergeometric distribution question that I posted about [earlier this evening](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923163/hypergeometric-rv-what-is-the-sample-population) is what follows:

$$\frac{{30 \choose 10}{20 \choose 5}}{{50 \choose 15}}$$

This becomes:
$$\frac{\frac{30!}{10!20!}\frac{20!}{5!15!}}{ \frac{50!}{15!35!}}$$
$$\frac{30! \cdot 35!}{10!\cdot5!\cdot50!}$$
$$\frac{30! \cdot 35!}{10!\cdot5!\cdot50!}$$

I see that I can, for example, cancel out 35! on the numerator and then that makes the 50! become $50\cdot49\cdots36$, so you get:
$$\frac{30!}{10!\cdot5!\cdot(50\cdot49\cdots36)}$$
and subsequently you can do:
$$\frac{(30\cdot29\cdots11)}{5!\cdot(50\cdot49\cdots36)}$$, but is there some way to compute these if I didn't have a computer or a long time to perform the arithmetic? I know there are a few expansions but they seemed to be not particularly helpful either...

Thanks

Comment: These days, a pocket calculator can usually deal with numbers this size. You might want to use Stirling's formula to get an estimate if you were working by hand, especially if the numbers were a bit bigger. You'd need tables of logarithms to work out the details.

Answer (score 2):

I actually performed the calculation(all by hand,none with calculator).
$$\zeta=\frac{30.29.28.27.26.25.24.23.22.21.20.19.18.17.16.15.14.13.12.11}{5.4.3.2.1.50.49.48.47.46.45.44.43.42.41.40.39.38.37.36}
$$
Cancelling(Writing explicitly took me 1 min $[9:10\to9:11]$ and cancelling took me 3 mins$[9:12\to9:15]$):
$$\zeta=\frac{9.11.13.17.29}{37.41.43.47}$$
Multiplying(Took me 2 mins $[9:17\to9:19]$)
$$\zeta=\frac{634491}{3065857}$$
Dividing(Took me 2 mins$[9:21\to9:23]$)
$$\zeta=0.206+\frac{2924458\times10^{-\text{something}}}{3065857}$$
So it's good to approx:
$$\zeta\approx0.206$$
Total $8$ mins. I hope you'll do better.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the accuracy you are looking for the approximation. A standard tool to approximate large binomial coefficients is the [Central Limit Theorem](http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/CLT.html). We have that:
$$\frac{1}{2^{30}}\binom{30}{10}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{30\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{2(15-10)^2}{30}},$$
$$\frac{1}{2^{20}}\binom{20}{5}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{20\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{2(10-5)^2}{20}},$$
$$\frac{1}{2^{50}}\binom{50}{15}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{50\pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{2(25-15)^2}{50}},$$
hence your ratio is around:
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{6\pi}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{5}{3}-\frac{5}{2}+4\right)=\frac{e^{-1/6}}{\sqrt{6\pi}}\approx 0.195.$$
This is not much different from approximating the original hypergeometric distribution with a normal distribution. Using the Stirling's approximation 
$$ n! \approx n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2\pi n}\,e^{\frac{1}{12n}}$$
is another option.